# ES6 equivalent of the following pattern?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next, es6-class

I want to use static class properties (stage-0) in ES6 classes like so -

```
class Button {
  static size = {
    SMALL: "SMALL",
    BIG: "BIG"
  }
}

class UILibrary {
  consturctor() {
    this.button = new Button();
  }
}

// I can't access static properties of a class instance :(
const LibraryA = new UILibrary();
console.log(LibraryA.button.size.SMALL);
```

What is the best alternative for this?

**EDIT**:

This question is not about creating class properties in ES6/7 which is already supported in stage-0, nor about creating static methods. I am just looking to find a pattern that allows attaching of enum-like objects to class instances. Hence none of the duplicate question suggestions are valid.

Comment: `I don't understand why` - java and javascript are totally unrelated languages

Comment: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/define-static-properties-and-prototype-properties-with-the-class-syntax

Comment: @JaromandaX Lol, that's true. But I would like to know if there is a reason for doing so from a best practices point of view.

Comment: `a reason for doing so` - doing what? all you've asked is why javascript isn't like java - it's like asking why java isn't like c++

Comment: @user3210476: Because JavaScript distinguishes instances from class objects (instead of mixing them up like Java, which doesn't even have class objects).

Comment: Alright. Not looking to have a java vs. javascript debate here. Just want the best alternative to the above code pattern.

Comment: Good ol' [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals)?

Comment: @noppa Not sure what you mean. But using object literals without `static` would mean memory is allocated for the enums on every instance of the Class, which seems like a waste.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't access static properties of a class instance :(

Yes, if they are static properties then you need to access them on the constructor:

```
console.log(Button.size.SMALL);
console.log(LibraryA.button.constructor.size.SMALL);
```

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648214/1048572) for a discussion of the differences)

> I am just looking to find a pattern that allows attaching of enum-like objects to class instances.

If you want them to be available on the instances, just don't make them `static`:

```
class Button {
  // without the experimental syntax, do the assignment in the constructor
  size = {
    SMALL: "SMALL",
    BIG: "BIG"
  }
}
```

or, instead of dropping the `static` keyword, just put them on the prototype so that the object isn't recreated over and over:

```
class Button {}
Button.prototype.size = {
  SMALL: "SMALL",
  BIG: "BIG"
};
```

Or maybe you shouldn't put them enum on the class at all, and just use named exports of an ES6 module.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Prototype alternative looks interesting. Does it have any performance hits though?

Comment: @user3210476: No, it takes less memory than the second sinppet in fact. The difference in lookup time between prototype properties and own properties is hardly measurable and depends a lot on the engine optimisations in place.