# ES6 React - static method vs constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I'm running into an "issue" where I don't know which one is the best option.

Say I have the following class

```
export default class A {
   constructor(){
       this.testMethod = function testMethod(){
           console.log('a')
       }
   }

   static testMethod2 = function() {
       console.log('B')
   }
}
```

now I'm extending this class

```
class C extends A {
    fetch() {
        this.testMethod()
        A.testMethod2()      
    }            
}
```

Defining it as a static method feels weird to use when extending it, I would assume the fact that I'm extending a class would allow me to access all of its own methods (ES5 prototype style)

I know both ways are correct but what's the best way to do this in ES6/React ? What are some caveats of both ways or performance issues ?

I'm currently using the constructor because it feels like the right/intended way of doing it but I can't "justify" one over the other.

All this came from applying the airbnb eslint to my code base (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this)

Comment: A `static` method is nothing more than a class method. If you don't intend on having class instances using that method then you have nothing to feel weird about.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why not just make it a normal non-static method?

Comment: Static methods are not subject of inheritance. What you do seems fine. What is the issue?

Comment: @Timo can't use it as a non-static method because I want to ensure the good practice of class methods to use this.

Comment: @trincot I know both are correct but I'm not sure, in a performance/readbility/good practice is the best way to implement (although I don't have to restrict myself to just one way of doing this)

Comment: It's as simple as this: If you intend to make methods that are to be used by instances of `A` or whatever instances inherit from it, simply create a regular instance method. If you'd like to create methods that pertain to the object itself, create a static method.

Answer (score 2):

> I would assume the fact that I'm extending a class would allow me to access all of its own methods

You actually can do that. Just call `C.testMethod2()` instead of `A.testMethod2()` (or [even use `this.constructor.testMethod2()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28627908/1048572)).

Defining functions that have nothing to do with a particular instance on the prototype or even inside the constructor is a bad practise, don't do that.

Comment: How come I can do C.testMethod2() but not this.testMethod() ? I think this just shows I need to grab a book...

Comment: Static methods are methods of the class (`A`, `C`) itself, not of the instances (`new A`, `new C`). If `this` refers to an instance, you only can access the properties that it inherits from the prototype objects (`A.prototype`, `C.prototype`).