# ES6: How to access a static getter from an instance

Tags: javascript, class, static, ecmascript-6, getter

How can i access a static getter from an instance of the class that implements that getter?

for example, i have this class:

```
class Component {
  static get isComponent() { return true; }

  constructor() {}
}

const c = new Component();
```

how can i call from "c" "isComponent" of "Component" class?
I read around and all I found is something like that:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(c).isComponent
```

but this is not working on my case because there is no "isComponent" method in Component prototype object. The above code works if I write the class like this:

```
Component.prototype.isComponent = () => { return true; }
```

but this is not the way i would like to write classes. What am I missing? tnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [es6 call static methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28627908/1048572)?

Comment: not exactly @Bergi

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`static`s become properties of the constructor function, which you can access on an instance via the `constructor` property:

```
console.log(c.constructor.isComponent);
```

```js
class Component {
  static get isComponent() { return true; }

  constructor() {}
}

const c = new Component();
console.log(c.constructor.isComponent); // true
```

Of course, that relies on `constructor` not having been mucked with. :-) Before the `class` syntax, you'd see people forgetting to set `constructor` properly in inheritance hierarchies all the time. Thankfully, with `class` syntax, it's handled automatically so people forgetting is no longer an issue.

In theory, the instance may have an "own" `constructor` property, shadowing the one on the prototype. So if that's a concern, you could go to the prototype:

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(c).constructor.isComponent);
```

```js
class Component {
  static get isComponent() { return true; }

  constructor() {}
}

const c = new Component();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(c).constructor.isComponent); // true
```

---

Alternatively, if you know what constructor it is, you can go direct to the source:

```
console.log(Component.isComponent);
```

```js
class Component {
  static get isComponent() { return true; }

  constructor() {}
}

// const c = new Component(); <== Don't need it
console.log(Component.isComponent); // true
```

...but only if you know in advance that `Component` is the constructor you want.

Answer (score -1):

The question you ask is wrong. You want the getter from an Instance of your Class but that not how statics work. I static is declared and initialized on the Class itself so if you want to get the value of it you should do it like this:

```
X = Component.isComponent
```

So don't call it on the instance but on the class itself. That sounds logical because a static does not have a this variable. The static has a value thats the same for all instances of your class.