# Call static methods when using default

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

When using ES6 modules and `export default class` how is it possible to call a static method from another method within the same class? My question refers specifically to when the class is marked as default (unlike [es6 call static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627908/es6-call-static-methods))

The below example illustrates how it is possible to call the static method from a non-static method when not using default, i.e. `Test.staticMethod()`?

```
export default class {
    static staticMethod(){
        alert('static');
    }

    nonStaticMethod(){
        // will not work because staticMethod is static.
        // Ordinarily you would use MyClass.staticMethod()
        this.staticMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand it - a static method gives you the ability to call that method without instantiating a "new Class". On the other hand you would need to type "new Class" in order to be able to call nonStaticMethod().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Can you make a utility class separate from the nonStaticMethod class and then you call Utils.staticMethod() inside your nonStaticMethod?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot introduce an auxiliray name after the `export default class` (like `export default class Foo`) and refer to the static method with the name? (`Foo.staticMethod`)? Would this work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [es6 call static methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627908/es6-call-static-methods)

Comment: @WiktorZychla yes this seems to be working actually. I was not aware that when using default you could also use an class name.

Comment: I will make an answer out of this comment, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [can use `this.constructor.…`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648214/1048572) if you dare, but the better solution would be to just name your class:

```
export default class MyClass {
    static staticMethod(){
        alert('static');
    }

    nonStaticMethod() {
        // Ordinarily you just use
        MyClass.staticMethod();
    }
}
```

---

If you cannot do this for some reason<sup>1</sup>, there's also this hack:

```
import MyClass from '.' // self-reference

export default class {
    static staticMethod(){
        alert('static');
    }

    nonStaticMethod() {
        // Ordinarily you just use
        MyClass.staticMethod();
    }
}
```

<sub>1: I cannot imagine a good one</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can name your exported class and refer to it by the auxiliary name:

```
export default class _ {

  static staticMethod(){
      alert('static');
  }

  nonStaticMethod(){
      _.staticMethod();
  }
}
```