# What is the difference between the following React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

What is the difference between the following methods of defining a react component?

Is the second method simply a shorter way of writing the same code? Will they both run and render exactly the same thing?

```
import React from 'react'

function MyApp() {
    return (
        <h1>
            Hello, World!
        </h1>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

```
import React from 'react'

export default function MyApp() {
    return (
        <h1>
            Hello, World!
        </h1>
    )
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the React component, but rather the way it is exported. Both examples showcase a different way to provide the same default export.

Comment: Check [export-an-es6-default-class-inline-with-definition-or-at-end-of-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60106063/export-an-es6-default-class-inline-with-definition-or-at-end-of-file) question. Possibly a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your question is more about the position of the `export default` statement. If this is the case, well in general if `MyApp` is the only thing you want to export then yes, these two methods will behave the same.