# Define method on class and instance in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, methods, static-methods

I want to be able to access a method from both the instance and the class:

```js
class AClass {
  // I want to make this both static and normal
  method() {
    console.log("Method called");
  }
}
```

I would expect to be able to access `static` methods from the instance (like in python with `@staticmethod`) but I can't as it gives an error:

```js
class AClass {
  static method() {
    console.log("Method called");
  }
}

AClass.method();  // this works
(new AClass).method();  // this doesn't work
```

#### Similar questions

- [Call static methods from regular ES6 class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627908/call-static-methods-from-regular-es6-class-methods)
  This question is not a duplicate of that question because I want the *same name* to both a static method and an instance method. That question is about calling a static method from an instance method (different name)

Comment: No, I want the *same name* to both a static method and an instance method. That question is about calling a static method from an instance method (different name)

Comment: @MarcellPerger then just name them the same?

Comment: So, why not just assign a property to the instance in the constructor? `constructor() { this.method = AClass.method; }`

Comment: If I have lots of static methods on the object, the constructor could get very long and I would prefer to keep the each function in one area of the code, but its still better than nothing.

Comment: "*`(new AClass).method();`, this doesn't work*" - this **should** not work. Why would you call a static method, which is not related to instances, on an instance? JavaScript is not Java, just use `AClass.method()` that works. If you really need to, `(new AClass).constructor.method()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a non-static method of the same name and call the static method from the non-static method.

```js
class AClass {
  static method() {
    console.log("Method called");
  }
  method() {
    AClass.method();
  }
}

AClass.method();  // this works
(new AClass).method();  // this now works
```

Comment: This is in almost the same as [Berhi's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648214) but with the crucial difference that it's worse, since it will not respect inheritance. Consider `class A { static method() { /* logic for a */ } }` and then a `class B extends A { static method() { /* logic for B */} }` By directly calling the static method from `A` the one defined in `B` will be ignored. Whereas with `this.constructor.method()` the child method, if any, would be used. Demo: https://jsbin.com/wucaxifali/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @VLAZ [Avoid answering questions with comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: I've answered the question with a duplicate already. This comment was a critique of the answer pointing out a flaw that is already solved in the duplicate. Speaking of: avoid answering duplicates.