# How to call a static method in javascript from a string name?

Tags: javascript

I have a class lets say a test1 that has static methods #a and #b and is called from a public method lets say message(methodName) that has the argument, methodName (either a or b) that decided which method to call. If a and be were not static, I could do this

```js
class test1 {
    message(methodName) {
    this[methodName]
    }
    a() {
    }
    b() {
    }
}
```

but because  they are static, I wanted to do,

```js
    class test1 {
    message(methodName) {
    this["#"+methodName]
    }
    #a() {
    }
    #b() {
    }
}
```

But it does not work. Am i doing something wrong or is there some other way??

Comment: `#` does not mean "static". It means **private**

Comment: If you actually wanted `static`, then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627908/call-static-methods-from-regular-es6-class-methods