# Unsetting <Object>.prototype.constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

In JavaScript, when I define a new function

```
function Foo () { /* code */ }
```

The prototype of this function is set to a new object and that object's `constructor` is set to the newly created function itself, so

```
Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo
```

This behaviour is well-described both in the ECMAScript spec and also on a more human-friendly [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor).

**Is this property used in any other way than being just a friendly shortcut to get to the constructor function?**

For example, if I were to

```
delete Object.prototype.constructor
```

(which I can, because, at least in Node.js, the property is defined as **writable** and **configurable**), am I somehow affecting the language's functionality?

After some rudimentary tests it does not seem to affect defining creating new objects as the property is defined properly for each new function / object I create.

> Note: I am aware that this could break 3rd party code - I am only interested in the core language's functionality.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012998/what-it-the-significance-of-the-javascript-constructor-property