# Omitting prototype.constructor changes prototype chain

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm trying to understand inheritance in JavaScript and I've seen that in JavaScript there are different ways to accomplish inheritance.  One such way is based off of an example from the Mozilla site which does something similar to the code below:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}

Person.prototype.setName = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

function Employee(name, Id) {
  Person.call(this, name);
  this.Id = Id;
}

Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;

Employee.prototype.getId = function() {
  return this.Id;
}

Employee.prototype.setId = function(Id) {
  this.Id = Id;
}

var andrew = new Employee("Andrew", "123");
```

I understand that this code is pretty basic and that I don't really need to define getters and setters.  I only added them to show that I can add to each of the prototype objects.  For the most part I understand what this code does.

**Where I start to get confused is when I see the following line**:

```
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;
```

I understand that we are setting the constructor property of the `Employee.prototype` object to point to the Employee constructor function.  I have read other posts from this site that say I can omit this line and indeed if I do, everything works as expected.  But...  When I do omit this line I see some changes to the prototype chain.  The `__proto__` property of the Employee object now points to a generic Object with the following methods: `getId` and `setId`.  The `__proto__` property of this object then points to the `Person.prototype` object.

### So my question is:

why is it that when I omit `Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee` that the `__proto__` property points to an generic object with the methods I set in the `Employee.prototype` object and not the `Employee.prototype` object itself?  Further more, how are the `getId` and `setId` methods attached to this mysterious prototype and is there any performance hit because of this?

I have attached the console.logs from the Chrome console to show the `__proto__` property when manually setting the constructor property and then when omitting it.

[image: With Employee.prototype.constructor]

[image: Without Employee.prototype.constructor]

Comment: I take it you've seen [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: @Liam - Thanks for the link.  I will read this over.  I have done a bunch of reading about inheritance just don't understand why I'm seeing different things in the console when omitting this piece of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects don't have names. So what you see next to `__proto__` is a name that the console infers *somehow*. Apparently that way involves `constructor` somehow.

**The prototype chain doesn't change**, only the information that is presented to you. `__proto__` refers to `Employee.prototype` regardless of the value of `constructor`.

---

Have a look at this example:

```js
var foo = {};
console.log(foo); // Object {}

foo.constructor = function Foo() {};
console.log(foo); // Foo {}
```

`foo` doesn't change here, it's a normal object. However, once `constructor` is set, it's presented as if it was an instance of `Foo`.

Comment: @Feliz - So in my code above, there is really no need to set the constructor since technically there is no change to the prototype chain.  I see that Mozilla has an example that does NOT omit this line.  Is it for clarify?  I ask because I want to find the most intuitive way and then stick with it.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: You probably want to read [What it the significance of the Javascript constructor property?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4012998/218196)

Answer (score 2):

Seems that Chrome simply takes `constructor` property to display the Class name of the object in console.
So may create any object and simply assign any function to it's  `constructor` property. As a result - you'll see this name in console:

```
var obj = { prop: 1 };
obj.constructor = function MyName() {};
```

will show:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> ...the `__proto__` property points to an generic object with the methods I set in the `Employee.prototype` object and not the `Employee.prototype` object itself?

The "generic object" you're talking about ***is*** `Employee.prototype`. You can test this very easily yourself in Chrome by:

- right-clicking on the `__proto__: Object` line
- selecting "*Store as global variable*" from the menu to create a `temp1` varaible
- testing that `temp1 == Employee.prototype` is `true`