# What is constructor property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In the following code , what's the benefit of having a constructor for Cat?

```
function Mammal(){
}
Mammal.prototype.breathe = function(){
    // do some breathing
};
function Cat(){
}
Cat.prototype = new Mammal();
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
var garfield = new Cat();
console.log(garfield instanceof Cat);
```

With or without the constructor, it always prints `true`, as the result of checking `instanceof`.

In general do we have to bother setting the constructor?

Comment: when you overwrite the prototype of a function in JS you overwrite the constructor property as well. so you have to write back the constructor to it. so that when you create an object of `Cat` the constructor of cat would be called.

Comment: @MubashirHanif : But if I remove that line , it still works. why ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012998/what-it-the-significance-of-the-javascript-constructor-property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In previous versions of ECMAScript, `instanceof` [used the constructors in the object's prototype chain](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinaryhasinstance). In ES6, however, there is [a Symbol](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-well-known-symbols) that determines if an object is an `instanceof` a constructor, and that's more reliable since it takes a very delibarate effort to screw that Symbol.

However, an object's constructor can be useful in some cases where you want to create another object of the same type, e.g. for properly cloning an instance:

```
function clone(o) {
    var newO = new o.constructor()
    // copy properties
    return newO
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. btw isn't it better to use : `Cat.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype)` rather than `Cat.prototype = new Mammal()` ?

Comment: Yes, it is. And my `clone()` function could also use that. None of that is relevant to your question, but it's absolutely right.