# instanceof check works on subclass without setting constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, subclass, prototypal-inheritance

I have the following JavaScript code

```
function Parent() {
}

function Child() {
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```

Note the absence of the statement

```
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

My understanding is that as the `constructor` property has not been set the `instanceof` checks should fail for new instances of `Child` class.

```
var child = new Child();
child instanceof Child; //Should give false
```

I verified that the constructor is incorrectly set
[image]

But when I run `child instanceof Child` it gave me true

[image]

But it should be `false` as constructor property is not set on `Child`'s prototype to be `Child`.

**Environment**

```
Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.109 (64-bit)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor

Comment: @Bergi Although the answer to that question can be related to this question  , IMO the questions do differ.

Comment: @AseemBansal: The SO definition of "duplicate" is (perhaps surprisingly) not about the *questions* being the same, but whether the *answer* to an earlier question also answers this question. (It's also not pejorative; duplicates improve the odds of people finding the answer, by wording the questions differently.) I think Bergi's right. (He's good at duplicates.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My understanding is that as the constructor property has not been set the instanceof checks should fail for new instances of Child class.

The `constructor` property isn't used by `instanceof` at all. In fact, until ES2015 (aka ES6), the `constructor` property wasn't used for *anything* in JavaScript itself. It was *defined* as existing on the default objects the runtime assigns to the `prototype` property on functions, but not *used*.

Let's look at how `instanceof` works. Consider:

```
o instanceof Foo
```

As of ES2015, `instanceof` will check to see if `Foo` implements an internal operation called `@@hasInstance` and, if so, it will use that operation to ask `Foo` whether `o` is an instance.

In ES5 and earlier (or if `Foo` doesn't have that internal operation), `instanceof` will look to see if the object `Foo.prototype` points to is anywhere on `o`'s prototype chain. (If "prototype chain" is not a familiar term, see the * at the end of the answer and then come back.) If so, it returns `true`; if not, it returns `false`.

E.g., here's a conceptual implementaton of `instanceof`, hand-waving away some details:

```
function isAnInstance(obj, func) {
    // Start: ES2015+ part
    const hasInstance = func[Symbol.hasInstance];
    if (hasInstance) {
        return hasInstance.call(func, obj);
    }
    // End: ES2015+ part
    // Start: The OrdinaryHasInstance specification operation
    for (let p = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj); p; p = Object.getPrototypeOf(p)) {
        if (p === func.prototype) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    // End: The OrdinaryHasInstance specification operation
}
```

The functions built into JavaScript *do* have `@@hasInstance` (they inherit it from `Funtion`), but all it does is the OrdinaryHasInstance operation shown above. See the specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-instanceofoperator), [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryhasinstance), and [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype-@@hasinstance).

We can see that `constructor` isn't involved from your question, and also from this simple demonstration:

```js
var p = {};
var o = Object.create(p);
var Foo = function() {};
Foo.prototype = p;
console.log(o instanceof Foo);                // true
console.log(o.hasOwnProperty("constructor")); // false
console.log(
    Object.getPrototypeOf(o).constructor === Object
);                                            // true
```

Note that:

1. `o` wasn't created via `Foo`.
2. In fact, `Foo` didn't even *exist* until after `o` was created.
3. `o` doesn't have its own `constructor` property.
4. `o`'s prototype's `constructor` property is `Object`, not `Foo`.

...and yet `instanceof` says "Yep, looks like it's a Foo." :-) Purely because the object `Foo.prototype` points to is also on `o`'s prototype chain.

---

* **"prototype chain"**

You clearly know that objects in JavaScript have prototypes from which they inherit properties. Those prototypes are objects, and so *they* have prototypes. So you get a "chain" of prototypes.

Consider a two-level *(arguably three-level)* inheritance hierarchy, here in ES5:

```
function Base() {
}

function Derived() {
    Base.call(this);
}
Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
Derived.prototype.constructor = Derived;
```

...or in ES2015:

```
class Base {
}
class Derived extends Base {
}
```

Now we use it:

```
var d = new Derived();
```

*(Where you see "the `d` object" and similar in the below, I do of course mean "the object `d` refers to" — but that's really verbose.)*

Now, the `d` object's prototype is `Derived.prototype`. `Derived.prototype`'s prototype is `Base.prototype`. `Base.prototype`'s prototype is `Object.prototype`. `Object.prototype` doesn't have a prototype (its `[[Prototype]]` internal slot is `null`).

Those objects are the *prototype chain* underlying `d`, and they mean that `d` is `instanceof Object`, `instanceof Base`, and `instanceof Derived`.

Comment: Could you please rephrase this - " with the object that the prototype property of the function you used"? I am not able to understand its meaning. Perhaps a simple example?

Comment: @AseemBansal: You know, I wrote that sentence and thought "Hmmm, clear as mud?" Let's see if I can fix that. :-)

Comment: Wait, where does ES6 use the `.constructor` property for anything?

Comment: @Bergi: It's involved in the non-sugar aspects of `class`, primarily [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-speciesconstructor) and [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrayspeciescreate). I think it's part of what makes it possible to subclass arrays and promises. For instance, [`Promise.prototype.then`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-promise.prototype.then) uses *SpeciesConstructor*, which uses the `constructor` property on the promise.

Comment: @AseemBansal: I've reworded, and had already added an example. Does that make it clear?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ah, right, I forgot about species. Though there still is some discussion on how exactly that should look like iirc.

Comment: @Bergi: Well, it's in the spec now, so... :-)

Comment: Yes it is clear now. Just had to start a bounty about why MDN and Udacity course are telling to explicitly set this property. In case you are interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453887/why-is-it-necessary-to-set-the-prototype-constructor

Comment: …so they gonna change it with ES7. Or ES8. Whenever it fits them :-) Edit: Or maybe I misremember and it was only about the species symbol usage, not the constructor property.

Comment: @Bergi: Maybe. You know they don't jerk things around like that lightly...

Comment: @AseemBansal: No, the answers there are not outdated. Maybe also have a look at [What it the significance of the Javascript constructor property?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4012998/1048572) - it's convenience.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the links but as per the explanation in the comments here are the answers there not outdated?

Comment: @AseemBansal: No, what TJ reminded me of is a very special case, and doesn't apply to ES5 subclassing where you need to set the `.constructor` explicitly if *you* need it. If you're subclassing arrays or promises, you have to use ES6 `class` syntax anyway which sets the property automatically.

Comment: @Bergi If I could I would give this comment the bounty. This cleared the whole confusion. Many thanks.