# how to check constructor of instance

Tags: javascript, constructor, instanceof

i created new instance('instance1' and 'instance2') using 'new' keyword. just like this.

1.with 'Child.prototype.constructor = Child'

```
function Parent() {

}

function Child() {
  Parent.call(this);
}

Child.prototype = new Parent();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

var instance1 = new Child();
```

2.without 'Child.prototype.constructor = Child'

```
function Parent() {

}

function Child() {
  Parent.call(this);
}

Child.prototype = new Parent();

var instance2 = new Child();
```

And i can check the constructor of instance using 'instanceof' keyword.

```
instance1 instanceof Child  // true
instance1 instanceof Parent // true
```

this result is make sense, because i clearly wrote 'Child.prototype.constructor = Child;'. so instanceof keyword can find both constructor. BUT

```
instance2 instanceof Child  // true
instance2 instanceof Parent // true
```

.
but this result is not make sense for me. i expected

```
instance2 instanceof Child  // false
```

because i did not write 'Child.prototype.constructor = Child;'.

Why???

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656957/632951

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537995/instanceof-check-works-on-subclass-without-setting-constructor

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` operator looks up if the `Constructor.prototype` object is present in the Prototype chain (`__proto__`) of the object being tested.

**So in your example:**

```
function Parent() {}

function Child() {
  Parent.call(this);
}

Child.prototype = new Parent();

var instance2 = new Child();
```

Since `instance2` is constructed from `Child()` constructor, the `__proto__` of `instance2` points to the prototype object of `Child()` constructor i.e. `Child.prototype`.

When you test for:

```
instance2 instanceof Child
```

`instanceof` operator will look if `Child.prototype` object is present in the prototype chain of `instance2`, which results in true since `instance2` was constructed from `Child()` constructor.
In other words:

```
instance2.__proto__ === Child.prototype
```

**Taking your example of second case:**

```
instance2 instanceof Parent
```

Here also `instance2`'s prototype chain i.e. (`__proto__`) has `Parent.prototype` object it will evaluate to true. i.e.

```
instance2.__proto__.__proto__ === Parent.prototype
```

**Final Note:**

`instanceof` operator works very much like the above conditional checks to test whether an object is an instance of a constructor. The `constructor` property present on Constructor function's `prototype` object is never used by `instanceof` operator while testing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but still im not clear. 
`instance2.__proto__`
return "Parent" and 
`Child.prototype` 
is also return "Parent". 

so i can understand instance2 is linked to "Parent"

but i think there is no connection between "instance2" and "Child" constructor. but 

`instance2 instanceof Child`

return "true".

how to know instance2 link to Child.