# Parasitic Combination Inheritance, rewrite inheritPrototype function.

Tags: javascript, javascript-inheritance

Below is a classic example for Parasitic Combination Inheritance. Can I rewrite inheritPrototype() as the following? Also, why need to set the "constructor" inside the function?

```
function inheritPrototype(subType, superType){

    subType.prototype = superType.prototype; //assign object
}
```

Classic Example

```
function object(my_object){
    function F(){}
    F.prototype = my_object;
    return new F();
}

function inheritPrototype(subType, superType){
    var x = object(superType.prototype); //create object
    x.constructor = subType; //augment object
    subType.prototype = x; //assign object
}

function SuperType(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.colors = [“red”, “blue”, “green”];
}

SuperType.prototype.sayName = function(){
    alert(this.name);
};

function SubType(name, age){
    SuperType.call(this, name);
    this.age = age;
}

// ***
inheritPrototype(SubType, SuperType);

SubType.prototype.sayAge = function(){
    alert(this.age);
};
```

Comment: No, you can't assign the prototype like that.  You will just have the same prototype object for both objects.  Any change to one would affect the other.  Use `subType.prototype = Object.create(super.prototype)` to create a new prototype object that is a copy of the other.

Comment: "Parasitic inheritance" does mean something entirely different. Please don't use that term.

Comment: Your `object` function is totally deprecated. Just use `Object.create` instead, and get a new tutorial/book/whatever.

Comment: For your second question (please ask only one per post), see [What it the significance of the Javascript constructor property?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4012998/1048572)