# Javascript Subclassing. Setting the constructor property

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, subclassing

For years I've been writing/extending my classes like so:

```
function Container(name, contents, logErrors){
    this.name = name;
    this.contents = contents;
    this.logErrors = logErrors || false;
}

function Group(contents){
    this.id = new Date().getTime();
    Container.call(this, 'Group_'+ this.id, contents);
}
Group.prototype = Object.create(Container.prototype);
Group.constructor = Group;
```

and yet, in some places I've seen the constructor property being assigned on the prototype of the subclass rather than directly on the subclass:

```
function Group(contents){
    this.id = new Date().getTime();
    Container.call(this, 'Group_'+ this.id, contents);
}
Group.prototype = Object.create(Container.prototype);
Group.prototype.constructor = Group; // <-----
```

#### Which is correct?

```
a) Group.prototype.constructor = Group;  
b) Group.constructor = Group;  
c) both a AND b  
d) neither a nor b
```

Please *cite your source* if possible.

Comment: `class Group extends Container {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use a)
Here's the reason why.

```
function Container(){
    // code
}
function Group(){
    // code
}
```

Observe that at this point of time

```
console.log(Group.prototype.constructor === Group);
// true
console.log(Group.constructor === Function);
// true
```

Now if you do

```
Group.prototype = Object.create(Container.prototype);
```

You loose the original `Group.prototype` and replaces all its methods as well. Which means you also lose the original `Group.prototype.constructor` as well.

Hence you may observe that at this point of time.

```
console.log(Group.prototype.constructor === Container);
// true
```

Now if you want something like a copy method.

```
Group.prototype.copy = function() {  
    return new this.constructor(this.contents);
};
```

You may end up getting the result

```
var group1 = new Group();
console.log(group1.copy() instanceof Group);
// false
```

Which may not be expected.

But if you would have done

```
Group.prototype.constructor = Group;
```

Then the results are as expected

```
console.log(group1.copy() instanceof Group);
// true
```

Also you can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Bergi, did you closed and then again opened this question.?

Answer (score 1):

Only *a)* is correct. The [point of the `.constructor` assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4012998/1048572) is that instances of your subclass (i.e. `Group`) inherit a `.constructor` property that points to the subclass constructor. They do inherit it from the subclasses' prototype object (i.e. `Group.prototype`) and nothing else.

You can also omit the statement entirely if none of your code is using the `.constructor` property.