# Something wrong when reset the javascript constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

I am trying to understand inheritance in javascript. 
I wrote a basic example to implement a simple inheritance between the parent object and a child. But I think there is something wrong when resetting the constructor.

```js
function Mammal(){
}
function Dog(){

}
Mammal.prototype.walk = function(){
    console.log('walking..walking....');
}
Dog.prototype.bark = function(){
    console.log('wof wof!');
}

Dog.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
let dogInstance = new Dog();
dogInstance.walk();
dogInstance.bark();
```

Comment: "*I think there is something wrong when resetting the constructor.*" - *what* do you think is wrong with that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think there is something wrong when resetting the constructor.

No, [there's not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4012998/1048572).

Your problem is that you do

```
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);
```

*after* having created the `bark` method on the old `Dog.prototype` object - which you are overwriting with a new, empty object. Just do it before any assignments:

```
function Mammal() {
}
Mammal.prototype.walk = function(){
    console.log('walking..walking....');
};

function Dog() {
}
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype); // do this before creating properties
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
    console.log('wof wof!');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here `Dog.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);`

Try it

## [Edit]

```
function Mammal() {}
function Dog() {}
Mammal.prototype.walk = function () {
    console.log( 'walking..walking....' );
};
Dog.prototype.bark = function () {
    console.log( 'wof wof!' );
};
```

## [/Edit]

```
let describe = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor;
let descriptor = Object.keys( Mammal.prototype ).reduce( function ( desc, key ) {
    desc[key] = describe( Mammal.prototype, key );
    return desc;
}, {} );
Dog.prototype = Object.create( Dog.prototype, descriptor );
```

## [Edit]

```
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
let dogInstance = new Dog();
dogInstance.walk();
dogInstance.bark();
```

Or use **Object Inheritance** follow this

```
function Mammal( key ) { this.key = key; }
function Dog() {
    Mammal.call( this, "Dog" );
}
Dog.prototype = Object.create( Mammal.prototype );
Dog.prototype.bark = function () {
    console.log( 'wof wof!' );
};
Mammal.prototype.walk = function () {
    console.log( 'walking..walking....' );
    return `${this.key} from Mammal.`;
};
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
let dogInstance = new Dog();
dogInstance.walk();
dogInstance.bark();
```

**Compare** `dogInstance`

```
 Mammal.prototype.isPrototypeOf( dogInstance );
 Dog.prototype.isPrototypeOf( dogInstance );
```

It's work for me :(

## [/Edit]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not completely sure about this, but this line is the problem:

```
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);
```

---

Apparently you can't give Mammal prototype directly to Dog prototype

```js
function Mammal() {
}
function Dog() {

}
Mammal.prototype.walk = function () {
 console.log( 'walking..walking....' );
}
Dog.prototype.bark = function () {
 console.log( 'wof wof!' );
}

Dog.prototype.mammal = Object.create( Mammal.prototype );
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;
let dogInstance = new Dog();
dogInstance.mammal.walk();
dogInstance.bark();
```

this seems to work

Comment: Running your fix on his snippet doesn't seem to solve the problem. Now it doesn't even recognize the `walk ` function.

Comment: ok...i'm trying on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3bv7nw2g/ and updated the answer...did you modify this line ? dogInstance.mammal.walk();